# Loop through columns having name T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this  query:

```
  Select ac.*,cp.NOMECAMPO as fieldname
FROM optes op 
    inner join  artico art on art.id=op.IDARTICO
    inner join SAM.ArtCla3ID13 ac on ac.idartico=art.id 
    inner join CAMPIPERS cp on cp.TABELLA = 'ArtCla3ID3'
WHERE op.id = 54782.000000
```

that returns something like this:

```
    rivestimento | numtaglienti | raggio | diamscarico | fieldname    |
    ______________________________________
    nuda         |       0      |    0   |     1     |  diamscarico |
    nuda         |       0      |    0   |     1     |  diamscarico |
```

How can I have this?

```
diamscarico |  1
raggio      |  0
numtaglienti|  0
rivestimento|  nuda
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the result of your query into an XML variable and do the unpivot when querying the XML.

```
declare @XML xml

set @XML = 
  (
    -- Your query goes from here
    select *
    from YourTable
    -- to here
    for xml path(''), type
  )

select T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname') as ColumnNaame,
       T.X.value('./text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
from @XML.nodes('*') as T(X)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/844f9/1)

Comment: It works with static table names but i need it to be dynamic.

Comment: @marcoburrometo It can be done with dynamic SQL [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/844f9/5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**

```
WITH tbl AS (
  Select ac.*
  FROM optes op 
    inner join  artico art on art.id=op.IDARTICO
    inner join SAM.ArtCla3ID13 ac on ac.idartico=art.id 
    inner join CAMPIPERS cp on cp.TABELLA = 'ArtCla3ID3'
  WHERE op.id = 54782.000000 
)
SELECT DISTINCT upp.column_name , upp.[value] 
FROM tbl
UNPIVOT
([value] for column_name IN ([rivestimento], [numtaglienti], [raggio], [diamscarico])) upp
```

Comment: It works but all field must be of same datatype and lenght... 

Is it possible to convert all fields massively and use in UNIPIVOT a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

It works with static table names but i need it to be dynamic.

Here's my code

```
declare @artcla3 varchar(20)
declare @XML xml


select @artcla3='ArtCla3ID'+ convert(varchar,art.IDARTCLA3)
            FROM optes op inner join  artico art on art.id=op.IDARTICO
            WHERE op.id = 54782.000000 


exec sp_executesql N'
    set @XML = 
      (
        SELECT ac.*,cp.NOMECAMPO,cp.TITCAMPO
        FROM optes op 
            inner join  artico art on art.id=op.IDARTICO
            inner join sam.'+@artcla3+' ac on ac.idartico=art.id 
            inner join CAMPIPERS cp on cp.TABELLA = '''+@artcla3+'''
        WHERE op.id = 54782.000000 
        for xml path(''''), type
      )
', N'@XML xml',@XML=@XML


select T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname') as ColumnNaame,
       T.X.value('./text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Value
from @XML.nodes('*') as T(X)
```

Comment: Is this an answer that works for you or a comment to my answer or e complement to the question? If this is not an answer you should move it.